# Simplification of algebra.

Tags: algebra-precalculus

How to show that $(x^{1/4}-y^{1/4})(x^{3/4}+x^{1/2}y^{1/4}+x^{1/4}y^{1/2}+y^{3/4})=x-y$

Can anyone explain how to solve this question for me? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Expand. There will be many cancellations.

Answer (score 4):

This follows from the fact that $$x^4-y^4=(x^2-y^2)(x^2+y^2)=(x-y)(x+y)(x^2+y^2)=(x-y)(x^3+x^2y+xy^2+y^3)$$
Now just replace $x,y$ with $x^{\frac{1}{4}}$ and $y^{\frac{1}{4}}$.

It is known, in general that $$x^n-y^n=(x-y)(x^{n-1}+x^{n-2}y+\dots+xy^{n-2}+y^{n-1})$$ 
As can be seen [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Factorization#Sum.2Fdifference_of_two_nth_powers).

Answer (score 2):

Let $x = u^4$ and $y = v^4$, then the left hand side of the equation simplifies to:
$$
(u-v)(u^3 + u^2v + uv^2 + v^3)
$$

Now, you can choose to multiply directly:
$$
u^4 + \color{red}{u^3v} + \color{green}{u^2v^2} + \color{blue}{uv^3} - \color{red}{vu^3} - \color{green}{v^2u^2} - \color{blue}{v^3u} - v^4
$$
Terms of similar colour cancel out, and you get the result after putting back $x$ and $y$.

Answer (score 1):

Start with $$(x^{1/4}-y^{1/4})(x^{3/4}+x^{1/2}y^{1/4}+x^{1/4}y^{1/2}+y^{3/4}).$$
Then distribute the terms:
$$=(x+x^{3/4}y^{1/4}+x^{1/2}y^{1/2}+x^{1/4}y^{3/4})-(x^{3/4}y^{1/4}+x^{1/2}y^{1/2}+x^{1/4}y^{3/4}+y).$$
Regrouping them gives
$$(x-y)+(x^{3/4}y^{1/4}-x^{3/4}y^{1/4})+(x^{1/2}y^{1/2}-x^{1/2}y^{1/2})+(x^{1/4}y^{3/4}-x^{1/4}y^{3/4}).$$
The terms cancel out, giving
$$(x-y)+0+0+0=x-y.$$

$$$$